# Populating a table in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I'm trying to improve [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405545&seqNum=4) example for a diagram editor.

The example uses a *nodes* class with a few attributes unrelated to my needs. Right now I want to add a "list of arrays" to this *node* class in order to then populate a QTableView in the "properties" dialog. I already designed the properties dialog with the QTableView. I'm not even sure this is feasible/makes sense.

Basically the table must have 4 columns: *name*, *type*, *value* and *unit*.

Each row of the table is a certain "property" I need the node to have.

My question is: **how can/should I model the table at class level?** I ask this because I have been looking to QList, QVariant, QMap, QMultiMap and I can't figure out out to use them correctly, and none of the examples I found so far are any help either, at least for what I need to do. I saw something about the [QStandardItemModel](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qstandarditemmodel.html) class, and I think it relates to the solution, but I can't understand how/why.

To top it off, I'm a Qt/C++ beginner, so much of the dynamics and jargon in Qt/C++ are still elluding me.

If anyone could give me some pointers, that would be great.

**EDIT:**
This isn't getting much attention, and I don't know if its because I wasn't clear enough, but anyway, try to picture this:

- a *Node* has a *PropertyList*
- that *PropertyList* lists *Properties*
- *Properties* are sort of dictionaries, as they have **always** 4 attributes and respective values: *name*:(string), *type*:(string), *value*:(double) and *unit*:(string).
- one *Node* can only have one *PropertyList*; a *PropertyList* can have several *Properties*. Some *Nodes* will have 3 *properties*, others will have 4, etc...

Now, the *Nodes* are represented in a diagram via a QGraphicsScene with QGraphicsItem. You can access a *PropertiesDialog* widget that has a *QTableWidget* in it. This table will show the *PropertyList*.

I want to know what kind of "structure" I can create/define that enables me to easily insert/read data in the table widget - ie, I load the data into the *PropertiesList* of the *Node* and it shows up in the table widget; if I change the data in the table widget, it passes on to the *PropertiesList* of the *Node*.

Hope this helps clearing out any doubts that may arise.

Comment: The PropertyWidget should only contain property data of a selected Node. Thus, when you select a Node, pass that node to the PropertyWidget and let the PropertyWidget extract the PropertyList to populate its own data models used for editing. When a property value is changed, get the PropertyWidget tell the Node what the new values are and the Node can, in turn, modify the QGraphicsItem if necessary.

Comment: @RobbieE that is already being done. The properties dialog is only affecting the node it is supposed to. How should I define the data-members for the _Node_ class and how to I pass those members values to the table widget in the properties dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after a lot of hair pulling, I got what I needed.

My first step was to create a `Property` class. This class has functions to set or get a *name* string, a *type* string, a *value* double and a *unit* string.

Next, I updated the `Node` class to include functions to add and remove `Property` object pointers to a `QList<Property *>`. Also included was a `listProperties` function that returns all the `Property` objects from a certain `Node`.

After this, the function to populate the `QTableWidget` with a certain `Node`'s properties was coded like this:

```
    propertiesList = node->listMyProperties();

    for (int row = 0; row < propertiesList.size(); ++row) {
        Property *property = propertiesList.at(row);
        addRow();
        tableWidget->item(row, 0)->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, property->propertyName());
        tableWidget->item(row, 1)->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, property->propertyType());
        tableWidget->item(row, 2)->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, property->propertyValue());
        tableWidget->item(row, 3)->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, property->propertyUnit());
    }
```

And the `addRow()` function:

```
void PropertiesDialog::addRow()
{
    int row = tableWidget->rowCount();

    tableWidget->insertRow(row);

    QTableWidgetItem *item0 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item0->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, item0);

    QTableWidgetItem *item1 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item1->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    tableWidget->setItem(row, 1, item1);

    QTableWidgetItem *item2 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item2->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    tableWidget->setItem(row, 2, item2);

    QTableWidgetItem *item3 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item3->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    tableWidget->setItem(row, 3, item3);

    tableWidget->setCurrentItem(item0);
}
```

This produces what I needed: to have a class to hold the property values related to each node, and present them on a `QTableWidget`. Next step is to make the reverse path, meaning, when edits occur in the `QTableWidget`, those changes should propagate to the class. Now I think I can find my way, hope this helps anyone trying to find something related. I'll also update the tags and maybe edit the title to make it more relevant/meaningful.